# EnqueueCallback in VB.net

Tags: silverlight, unit-testing, c#-to-vb.net

I would like to perform a unit test in Silverlight, with VB.net.

I have read an example of how to perform an asynchronous test (http://jonas.follesoe.no/UnitTestingAsynchronousSilverlightCode.aspx), but I do not know how to translate the following from C# to VB.net:

```
EnqueueCallback(() => Assert.AreEqual(value, expectedValue));
```

Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
EnqueueCallback(Function() Assert.AreEqual(value, expectedValue))
```

Comment: +1 - wow - I had no idea that VB supported this kind of syntax! Works great.